# Main dask task with subtask stuck when finished if runned from django view

Tags: django, docker, dask, dask-distributed

I have a django view that should submit a task in dask. 
This scope of this task to unzip a filefield of a model and then run some other tasks that require the unzipped filepath as argument.

The following code is not the real one, but I have same issue also on this minimalist example.

The code to run the main task in django view is quite simple because is just a fire and forget:

```
dask_client = Client("tcp://scheduler:8786")
fire_and_forget(dask_client.submit(unzip_then_run, object))
```

The unzip_then_run code is made following  [instructions](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/task-launch.html)

```
def unzip_then_run_basic(dump, es_url):
    dask_client = get_client()
    secede()
    tasks = []
    for i in range(10):
        task = dask_client.submit(run_basic, i)
        tasks.append(task)
    results = dask_client.gather(taks)
    rejoin()
```

The final subtask code is:

```
def run_basic(random):
    time.sleep(random * 2)
    return 0
```

Everything works until the rejoin(), the subtasks end successfully but then nothing happen.
Everything seems to be waiting and I don't have information or issues on my worker logs:

[image]

The reason why I need to wait for subtasks is that I want to update the model with a completed status. If I use fire_and_forget also in the main task everything works fine but then I don't easily know when the task is completed.

All the code is running in a docker-compose environment using dask-docker and a django docker image.
If I run the following test code from the django docker image but as a script everything works fine.

```
import sys
import os
import django

sys.path.insert(0, "/app")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.local")
django.setup()

from website.models import Object
from dask.distributed import Client, fire_and_forget
from symbols.test.dask_util import unzip_then_run


object = Object.objects.get(pk=49)
dask_client = Client("tcp://scheduler:8786")
fire_and_forget(dask_client.submit(unzip_then_run, object))
```

There is something I need to take care of when running the code from django view?

Comment: Are you sure the django view invocation is not halted by any timeout? In other words, are you sure all the code block contained in the view is executed? Because I don't feel is a good idea to wait the end of an asynchronous task inside the view's block.
Are you able to checkout http status code of your response? If you are using a web browser you can check the packets exchanged and their status code. 
Because if the error is a 408, the web server kills the view's code before dask finishes.

Answer (score 1):

> There is something I need to take care of when running the code from django view?

Not as far as I know unfortunately.

Django is complex though and might be doing something unexpected.

The next thing to do here is probably to make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting MCVE, after one hour preparing the prototype I've discovered that i was waiting for the wrong variable
dask_client.gather(taks) instead of dask_client.gather(tasks)
Unfortunately with 6 workers the docker log wasn't readable due to heartbeat, but with a small new project I found the error.